How to add AZ Application Client ID to Sharepoint Site collection Owners group
I am in need of some critical automation for SharePoint Online and even though i'm able to perform all tasks, i'm restricted from using the App ID to "share a link" for a file in a Document Library (using the PnP cmdlet Add-PnPfileUserSharingLink). The reason being that we only allow Site Owners to share files/items. I'm able to use the Add-PnPFileUserSharingLink cmdlet using a regular AZ user account, but i get "access denied" if i try using the Client App ID remotely. So i find myself realizing that I need to add the Client App ID to the Site Owners Group, which would give me permission to execute the Add-PnPFIleUserSharingLink cmdlet. But after trying a few iterations of "i:0#.f|membership|appID@company.onmicrosoft.com" and "c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|" and "c:0t.c|tenant|" i seem to have hit a roadblock. Any guidance would be very appreciated. Thanks so much.

Is your app registration secured with a client secret or a certificate?

with a certificate. I'm inheriting a system that needs automation. Thanks

Access denied is the expected result if you are using a registered Entra ID application with a client secret. Due to security reinforcement, only certificate will work.

FAQ: Can I use other means besides certificates for realizing app-only access for my Azure AD app?
No, all other options are blocked by SharePoint Online and will result
in an Access Denied message.

Source: Granting access via Azure AD App-Only
Try to generate a new certificate for your application with application permissions Sites.FullControl.All and use it to connect to SharePoint:
$password = (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 'myprivatekeypassword' -Force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "contoso.sharepoint.com" -ClientId 6c5c98c7-e05a-4a0f-bcfa-0cfc65aa1f28 -CertificatePath 'c:\mycertificate.pfx' -CertificatePassword $password  -Tenant 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com'

Reference: Connect-PnPOnline


Thanks for the info! I will generate a certificate and see if i can bypass the access restrictions.
